# Selecting data from 3 tables, grouping by latest date value and another value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so I've been racking my brains on this for a while, and I think it's time to ask the collective!

I'm using SQLServer and I've got 3 tables, defined as such:

```
VolumeData

__________________________
| dataid | currentReading|
--------------------------
|   1    |      22       |
|   7    |      33       |
|   9    |      25       |
|   12   |      12       |
--------------------------

LatestData

________________________________________________________________
| dataid | unitNumber | unitLocation |      dateTimeStamp      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |  2344454   |      2       | 2017-07-10 13:16:29.000 |
|   7    |  2344451   |     44       | 2017-07-10 13:22:29.000 |
|   9    |  2344456   |     92       | 2017-07-10 12:16:29.000 |
|   12   |  2344456   |     12       | 2017-07-10 12:13:23.000 |
----------------------------------------------------------------

unitData

____________________________________________________________________________________
| unitNumber | unitLocation | buildingNumber | officeNumber | officeName | country |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2344454  |      2       |       44       |       1      |  Telford   |    UK   |
|   2344451  |     44       |       22       |       1      |  Telford   |    UK   |
|   2344456  |     92       |       12       |       2      |  Hamburg   |    GER  |
|   2344456  |     12       |       33       |       2      |  Hamburg   |    GER  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to retrieve just the latest currentReading (based on the dateTimeStamp field in LatestData) along with the following fields, grouped on the unitNumber:

```
currentReading, unitNumber, officeName, country, buildingNumber
```

One more thing to note is that records can arrive in any order.

The following is one example that I tried, I've tried many more but I've not kept them open unfortunately:

```
SELECT 
      a.currentReading
      ,MAX(b.dateTimeStamp)
      ,c.unitNumber
      ,c.country
      ,c.officeName
  FROM [VolumeData] a INNER JOIN LatestData b ON a.dataid = b.dataid INNER JOIN
    unitData c ON c.[unitNumber] = b.[unitNumber] AND c.[unitLocation] = b.[unitLocation];
```

This results in: `Column 'VolumeData.currentReading' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Any advice would be much appreciated! Everything I try either results in retrieving far too many rows or results in logical SQL errors. I should also add that these tables contain millions of rows, and grow daily, so I'm looking for a really efficient way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service.  You've been racking your brain.  Don't tell me you got nothing.

Comment: Quite aware of that - I have been trying this for hours, I don't have all my examples as they've been iterated upon, but sure, I'll add in some non-working SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same logic as [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890743/eric)'s answer, probably a bit cleaner using CTE and joins lesser records.

```
DECLARE @VolumeData TABLE
( 
    dataid          int, 
    currentReading  int
); 

INSERT INTO @VolumeData VALUES(1, 22);
INSERT INTO @VolumeData VALUES(7, 33);
INSERT INTO @VolumeData VALUES(9, 25);
INSERT INTO @VolumeData VALUES(12,12);

DECLARE @LatestData TABLE
( 
    dataid          int, 
    unitNumber      int,
    unitLocation    int,
    dateTimeStamp   datetime
); 

INSERT INTO @LatestData VALUES(1,  2344454, 2,  '2017-07-10 13:16:29.000');
INSERT INTO @LatestData VALUES(7,  2344451, 44, '2017-07-10 13:22:29.000');
INSERT INTO @LatestData VALUES(9,  2344456, 92, '2017-07-10 12:16:29.000');
INSERT INTO @LatestData VALUES(12, 2344456, 12, '2017-07-10 12:13:23.000');

DECLARE @UnitData TABLE
( 
    unitNumber      int,
    unitLocation    int,
    buildingNumber  int,
    officeNumber    int,
    officeName      varchar(50),
    country         varchar(50)
); 

INSERT INTO @UnitData VALUES(2344454, 2,  44, 1, 'Telford', 'UK');
INSERT INTO @UnitData VALUES(2344451, 44, 22, 1, 'Telford', 'UK');
INSERT INTO @UnitData VALUES(2344456, 92, 12, 2, 'Hamburg', 'GER');
INSERT INTO @UnitData VALUES(2344456, 12, 33, 2, 'Hamburg', 'GER');

WITH LatestData_CTE (dataid, unitNumber, unitLocation, dateTimeStamp, rowNum)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT  dataid
          , unitNumber
          , unitLocation
          , dateTimeStamp
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unitNumber ORDER BY dateTimeStamp DESC) AS rowNum
    FROM @LatestData
)  
SELECT currentReading, l.unitNumber, officeName, country, buildingNumber
 FROM LatestData_CTE l 
    INNER JOIN @VolumeData v ON v.dataid = l.dataid 
    INNER JOIN @UnitData u ON u.[unitNumber] = l.[unitNumber] AND u.[unitLocation] = l.[unitLocation]
WHERE l.rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to order the date.  Then you just take the first one, which correspond to the latest date.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a.currentReading
        , b.dateTimeStamp
        , c.unitNumber
        , c.country
        , c.officeName
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.unitNumber ORDER BY b.dateTimeStamp DESC) AS rowNum
    FROM [VolumeData] a 
    INNER JOIN LatestData b ON a.dataid = b.dataid 
    INNER JOIN unitData c ON c.[unitNumber] = b.[unitNumber] AND c.[unitLocation] = b.[unitLocation]
) a
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not complete code, but an advice - It can be implemented by ROW_NUMBER function in CTE

Similar to

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/597b876e-eb00-4013-a613-97c377408668/rownumber-and-cte?forum=transactsql

http://datachix.com/2010/02/10/use-a-common-table-expression-and-the-row_number-function-to-eliminate-duplicate-rows-3/

Just google CTE+ROW_NUMBER to get more examples.

So in CTE you join all required tables and you apply ROW_NUMBER over partition, ordered by dateTimestamp (DESC) and then you use WHERE CTE_name.Rank = 1 in the query that uses that CTE.